# Matching Point to Polygon in R with two different datatable

Tags: r, dataframe, r-sf

I would like to ask how can I retrieve a specific column from the newsubzone datatable and append to the zip_code_new datatable based on the point data at zip_code_new. So if zip_code_new point data is found inside the geometry of the newsubzone, it will retrieve the PLN_AREA_N and REGION_N.

head(dput of zip_code_new)

```
structure(list(ZipCode = c("", "100047", "101080", "101110", 
"102092", "109030"), Count = c(1950, 2, 6, 5, 24, 2), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("XY", "POINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(103.8099, 1.2723), class = c("XY", "POINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(103.8062, 1.2741), class = c("XY", "POINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(103.8092, 1.2817), class = c("XY", "POINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(103.8071, 1.2758), class = c("XY", "POINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(103.8078, 1.2717), class = c("XY", "POINT", 
    "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 103.8062, 
ymin = 1.2717, xmax = 103.8099, ymax = 1.2817), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "EPSG:3414", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"SVY21 / Singapore TM\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"SVY21\",\n        DATUM[\"SVY21\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4757]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Singapore Transverse Mercator\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",1.36666666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",103.833333333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",1,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",28001.642,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",38744.572,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"northing (N)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"easting (E)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Cadastre, engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Singapore - onshore and offshore.\"],\n        BBOX[1.13,103.59,1.47,104.07]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3414]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(ZipCode = NA_integer_, 
Count = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

dput of newsubzone

```
structure(list(PLN_AREA_N = c("MARINA SOUTH", "OUTRAM", "SINGAPORE RIVER"
), REGION_N = c("CENTRAL REGION", "CENTRAL REGION", "CENTRAL REGION"
), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(list(structure(c(31495.5604999997, 
31980.9567, 32332.9018000001, 32362.3935000002, 32362.3239000002, 
32277.9312000005, 32277.6333999997, 32242.9775, 32243.8479000004, 
32244.7132999999, 32244.3973000003, 32243.1083000004, 32241.8640000001, 
32245.8387000002, 32246.5344000002, 32247.8010999998, 32247.5044999998, 
32249.2824999997, 32249.3515999997, 32250.4693, 32254.5171999997, 
32255.4546999997, 32255.4743999997, 32255.4968999997, 32256.6102999998, 
32276.3811999997, 32276.1440000003, 32276.0007999996, 32275.9846000001, 
32275.9539000001, 32276.0461999997, 32276.3178000003, 32276.7603000002, 
32277.3603999997, 32278.0998, 32278.9561000001, 32279.9034000002, 
32280.9128999999, 32281.9539000001, 32282.9949000003, 32284.0044, 
32284.9517000001, 32285.8080000002, 32286.5473999996, 32287.1475, 
32287.5899999999, 32287.8616000004, 32287.9539000001, 32287.8903999999, 
32287.7012999998, 32287.3905999996, 32286.9649, 32286.4331999999, 
32285.8066999996, 32284.9581000004, 32284.0198999997, 32283.0201000003, 
32281.9885, 32280.9559000004, 32279.9529999997, 32279.0098000001, 
32278.1544000003, 32256.9166000001, 32257.8276000004, 32261.8335999995, 
32270.0332000004, 32273.3463000003, 32281.7202000003, 32295.7961999997, 
32303.8572000004, 32312.7582, 32317.1201999998, 32316.7721999995, 
32310.7482000003, 32306.4331999999, 32306.0927999998, 32297.7161999997, 
32290.7127, 32286.0291999998, 32280.6732000001, 32270.4501999998, 
32259.3052000003, 32254.9271999998, 32237.5961999996, 32232.6812000005, 
32221.5401999997, 32211.3761999998, 32199.9002, 32176.9462000001, 
32164.9292000001, 32123.1572000002, 32117.4522000002, 32071.6282000002, 
32020.6551999999, 32007.6642000005, 31959.5341999996, 31894.7832000004, 
31822.5882000001, 31799.8881999999, 31795.3240999999, 31758.3572000004, 
31684.7105, 31677.2391999997, 31533.4844000004, 31321.7462999998, 
31142.1482999995, 31071.2812999999, 31013.2402999997, 30794.2752, 
30844.8712999998, 30895.4497999996, 30946.6431999998, 30967.699, 
30994.3548999997, 31040.7761000004, 31045.4472000003, 31083.6756999996, 
31115.1582000004, 31132.6443999996, 31139.2381999996, 31141.7147000004, 
31143.6639999999, 31146.1520999996, 31146.3316000002, 31147.2714, 
31147.4261999996, 31147.4323000005, 31148.1798, 31148.3777000001, 
31172.8687000005, 31173.5109999999, 31182.4841, 31183.1114999996, 
31203.6152999997, 31214.2324000001, 31225.6672, 31255.0745999999, 
31300.8302999996, 31313.8995000003, 31330.2385, 31358.0115, 31366.1854999997, 
31375.9933000002, 31389.0625, 31398.8885000004, 31409.5323999999, 
31422.6363000004, 31442.2971000001, 31446.3920999998, 31455.4528000001, 
31462.0445999997, 31464.5225, 31469.4614000004, 31477.6792000001, 
31491.6708000004, 31494.1398, 31495.5604999997, 30140.0122999996, 
29671.6034999993, 29331.9759999998, 29303.5164000001, 29303.4653999992, 
29241.6087999996, 29241.3905999996, 29215.9890999999, 29212.2470999993, 
29204.1143999994, 29197.3333000001, 29190.2301000003, 29185.5403000005, 
29178.9847999997, 29177.8373000007, 29175.7480999995, 29175.4389999993, 
29172.3607000001, 29172.2412, 29170.3060999997, 29163.2986999992, 
29161.5143999998, 29161.4768000003, 29161.4337000009, 29162.2482999992, 
29176.7128999997, 29177.4383000005, 29178.1878999993, 29178.3300999999, 
29178.9365999997, 29179.9774999991, 29180.9866000004, 29181.9332999997, 
29182.7888999991, 29183.5273000002, 29184.1262999997, 29184.5676000006, 
29184.8378999997, 29184.9288999997, 29184.8378999997, 29184.5676000006, 
29184.1262999997, 29183.5273000002, 29182.7888999991, 29181.9332999997, 
29180.9866000004, 29179.9774999991, 29178.9365999997, 29178.0661999993, 
29177.2141999993, 29176.3987000007, 29175.6368000004, 29174.9448000006, 
29174.3372000009, 29173.7430000007, 29173.3036000002, 29173.0321999993, 
29172.9367999993, 29173.0203000009, 29173.2802000009, 29173.7085999995, 
29174.2929999996, 29158.7312000003, 29156.9970999993, 29149.3714000005, 
29133.7627000008, 29127.0516999997, 29110.0897000004, 29076.9317000005, 
29052.9427000005, 29024.8157000002, 28996.0607999992, 28973.8628000002, 
28915.5877, 28897.2397000007, 28896.2606000006, 28872.1646999996, 
28856.1129999999, 28845.3786999993, 28835.2027000003, 28818.7737000007, 
28804.5467000008, 28799.7807, 28780.9156999998, 28775.3206999991, 
28763.1406999994, 28754.9057, 28746.3387000002, 28729.8637000006, 
28721.5756999999, 28690.5117000006, 28686.4427000005, 28654.0797000006, 
28616.1736999992, 28606.5087000001, 28570.5156999994, 28523.7786999997, 
28471.0406999998, 28454.3676999994, 28451.0146999992, 28423.1837000009, 
28369.4679000005, 28374.5405999999, 28468.3885999992, 28602.9434999991, 
28717.5032000002, 28762.7070000004, 28804.3048, 28944.9921000004, 
29021.9593000002, 29098.8998000007, 29176.7756999992, 29208.8066000007, 
29257.3065000009, 29341.2080000006, 29349.6503999997, 29446.4063000008, 
29545.4121000003, 29648.8651999999, 29724.8848000001, 29816.8340000007, 
29900.6015000008, 30000, 30007.1794000007, 30044.7695000004, 
30053.5874000005, 30053.9430999998, 30096.4765000008, 30107.6692999993, 
30107.4133000001, 30107.4066000003, 30107.3127999995, 30107.3061999995, 
30107.0919000003, 30106.1633000001, 30105.2256000005, 30103.2829, 
30101.1697000004, 30100.2150999997, 30099.2268000003, 30097.3007999994, 
30097.2152999993, 30097.1127000004, 30096.1580999997, 30097.6916000005, 
30099.216, 30101.5326000005, 30105.4163000006, 30106.1903000008, 
30112.6388000008, 30117.4760999996, 30119.9042000007, 30123.1232999992, 
30127.1267000008, 30135.9761999995, 30137.5854000002, 30140.0122999996
), dim = c(157L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"
)), structure(list(list(structure(c(29092.2751000002, 29119.6405999996, 
29144.0066999998, 29144.0082999999, 29176.9993000003, 29213.8704000004, 
29230.4314000001, 29237.2291999999, 29249.9767000005, 29280.7559000002, 
29297.1429000003, 29304.4434000002, 29325.7779999999, 29333.9323000005, 
29313.7342999997, 29289.7187999999, 29264.5005000001, 29228.8803000003, 
29209.2632999998, 29189.0327000003, 29161.2005000003, 29147.2006999999, 
29138.4175000004, 29138.1714000003, 29129.7049000002, 29121.5690000001, 
29119.023, 29107.5661000004, 29094.0009000003, 29069.4118999997, 
29058.1415999997, 29058.0773, 29039.8369000005, 29018.1453, 28998.3821, 
28998.3221000005, 28966.7690000003, 28959.9426999995, 28959.8520999998, 
28958.7725999998, 28957.8219999997, 28957.0054000001, 28956.3267999999, 
28955.7894000001, 28955.3958000001, 28955.1481999997, 28955.0476000002, 
28954.5395999998, 28954.4085999997, 28954.4062999999, 28954.4842999997, 
28954.7177999998, 28955.1056000004, 28942.3328999998, 28898.2675000001, 
28893.2084999997, 28889.6562999999, 28883.3557000002, 28883.2070000004, 
28882.4719000002, 28881.8482999997, 28874.5990000004, 28874.1865999997, 
28874.5184000004, 28874.5171999997, 28874.5713999998, 28874.6108999997, 
28874.3810999999, 28874.0810000002, 28873.5876000002, 28872.8349000001, 
28871.665, 28869.5171999997, 28865.7209999999, 28864.6731000002, 
28855.3097000001, 28848.1409, 28838.9533000002, 28830.9022000004, 
28827.9753, 28822.9336999999, 28820.8340999996, 28820.9786999999, 
28821.3931, 28821.9881999996, 28822.0343000004, 28822.0628000004, 
28823.4939999999, 28814.4923999999, 28805.9100000001, 28801.6843999997, 
28795.6721999999, 28794.3992999997, 28794.057, 28792.8816, 28791.4199000001, 
28789.5987, 28788.6886999998, 28787.0429999996, 28785.4625000004, 
28782.6935999999, 28782.0878999997, 28780.5665999996, 28779.4217999997, 
28779.1564999996, 28777.4715, 28774.1469999999, 28767.6557999998, 
28761.5449000001, 28758.4157999996, 28753.3551000003, 28752.3504999997, 
28751.2641000003, 28750.8903999999, 28745.7144999998, 28743.6518999999, 
28742.9411000004, 28739.7414999995, 28732.6646999996, 28732.6199000003, 
28732.5310000004, 28732.4880999997, 28732.3629000001, 28732.3186999997, 
28732.2740000002, 28732.2292999998, 28732.1481999997, 28732.1031999998, 
28732.0245000003, 28731.9892999995, 28731.9483000003, 28731.8771000002, 
28731.8355999999, 28731.7962999996, 28731.7560000001, 28731.6764000002, 
28731.6366999997, 28731.5590000004, 28731.5126, 28731.4335000003, 
28731.3876999998, 28731.2248999998, 28731.1783999996, 28731.1344999997, 
28731.0903000003, 28730.9978, 28730.9578, 28730.875, 28730.8618000001, 
28730.7955999998, 28730.7832000004, 28730.6276000002, 28730.6151999999, 
28730.5031000003, 28730.4901999999, 28728.4348999998, 28726.1030000001, 
28723.1440000003, 28720.7825999996, 28716.9977000002, 28714.9730000002, 
28712.6530999998, 28711.7048000004, 28710.0515000001, 28705.6431, 
28699.6859999998, 28696.7110000001, 28696.1868000003, 28687.3481999999, 
28678.4501999998, 28678.4404999996, 28678.1988000004, 28677.6955000004, 
28674.1664000005, 28671.4242000002, 28668.0221999995, 28665.0262000002, 
28663.4084999999, 28662.4364999998, 28658.8820000002, 28655.5307999998, 
28652.7885999996, 28648.6248000003, 28645.2734000003, 28642.4298, 
28640.8002000004, 28638.8152999999, 28636.3826000001, 28633.4784000004, 
28631.2028000001, 28628.8651999999, 28626.3317999998, 28624.2092000004, 
28621.6963999998, 28620.9143000003, 28619.5504999999, 28619.1449999996, 
28617.6054999996, 28617.5223000003, 28617.2745000003, 28615.2132999999, 
28614.6036, 28612.9293, 28612.9071000004, 28612.7917999998, 28612.8064000001, 
28611.9949000003, 28611.8864000002, 28611.8794999998, 28611.7999999998, 
28608.4517999999, 28608.4451000001, 28605.1013000002, 28604.8525, 
28570.5980000002, 28569.6699000001, 28569.1708000004, 28568.5601000004, 
28568.5500999996, 28544.4758000001, 28544.4348999998, 28534.7093000002, 
28533.8214999996, 28533.1179999998, 28514.3673, 28485.9556, 28451.8340999996, 
28423.7796, 28405.5674000001, 28382.5049999999, 28344.3775000004, 
28295.6346000005, 28295.5845999997, 28257.9403999997, 28246.9199000001, 
28241.1281000003, 28225.2905000001, 28197.6029000003, 28197.6009, 
28194.8651999999, 28192.8633000003, 28177.5996000003, 28167.6697000004, 
28167.6584999999, 28160.2259, 28161.2835999997, 28161.2947000004, 
28161.9011000004, 28163.5892000003, 28164.6332, 28166.9790000003, 
28172.7734000003, 28180.4656999996, 28181.8419000003, 28187.3740999997, 
28191.4929999998, 28195.2958000004, 28195.8581999997, 28197.7037000004, 
28198.5981999999, 28200.1929000001, 28201.3760000002, 28201.4842999997, 
28206.8848999999, 28223.9349999996, 28226.926, 28241.4850000003, 
28279.4858999997, 28312.5367999999, 28330.2800000003, 28330.0599999996, 
28339.6901000002, 28365.0678000003, 28364.3101000004, 28385.8191, 
28393.398, 28407.9330000002, 28420.3530000001, 28517.8380000005, 
28505.9199999999, 28545.3924000002, 28584.6479000002, 28587.2602000004, 
28587.3700000001, 28594.4104000004, 28603.7216999996, 28629.7341, 
28665.4457, 28692.4074999997, 28717.3408000004, 28753.2450999999, 
28771.2625000002, 28784.8940000003, 28790.3021, 28807.8236999996, 
28816.2986000003, 28831.9129999997, 28878.2352999998, 28879.6619999995, 
28884.0240000002, 28933.7917999998, 28933.8157000002, 28971.6743000001, 
29018.6108999997, 29032.3071999997, 29092.2751000002, 30021.8877000008, 
30006.6963, 29992.3150999993, 29992.3142000008, 29973.4837999996, 
29952.8676999994, 29943.4276999999, 29939.5527999997, 29932.2864999995, 
29914.3234000001, 29904.9421999995, 29900.7280999999, 29887.3238999993, 
29882.0004999992, 29858.6339999996, 29827.3170999996, 29794.4317000005, 
29751.2805000003, 29727.5768999998, 29704.7684000004, 29723.0709000006, 
29734.5464999992, 29741.7458999995, 29741.4677000009, 29731.8969000001, 
29721.9498999994, 29718.9419, 29705.4001000002, 29716.5319999997, 
29686.6050000004, 29673.5236000009, 29673.5761999991, 29688.5208000001, 
29662.0826999992, 29637.9948999994, 29638.0441999994, 29663.9399999995, 
29669.5401000008, 29669.3888000008, 29667.5831000004, 29665.7060000002, 
29663.7670000009, 29661.7753999997, 29659.7412, 29657.6743000001, 
29655.5850000009, 29653.4834000003, 29613.7007999998, 29603.4507999998, 
29603.068, 29600.9066000003, 29598.7563000005, 29596.6285999995, 
29596.6369000003, 29596.6655999999, 29596.6688999999, 29596.6711999997, 
29596.6753000002, 29596.6849000007, 29596.6801999994, 29596.6763000004, 
29596.6301000006, 29596.6274999995, 29589.8202999998, 29589.7193999998, 
29583.7100000009, 29579.3210000005, 29575.9955000002, 29573.6727000009, 
29570.9416000005, 29567.8530000001, 29564.2598999999, 29559.1755999997, 
29553.0576000009, 29551.3688999992, 29539.9503000006, 29531.2942999993, 
29520.2009999994, 29509.9524000008, 29505.0994000006, 29493.6057999991, 
29479.5767999999, 29470.8909000009, 29464.7522, 29452.1784000006, 
29443.4088000003, 29438.0222999994, 29426.1949000005, 29410.3855000008, 
29417.7245000005, 29421.3380999994, 29426.4792999998, 29425.6548999995, 
29425.4331999999, 29424.6105000004, 29423.6272, 29422.4997000005, 
29421.9554999992, 29421.0454999991, 29420.2978000008, 29418.9581000004, 
29418.6900999993, 29418.0168999992, 29417.5002999995, 29417.3927999996, 
29416.6471999995, 29415.1762000006, 29412.5558000002, 29410.2531000003, 
29408.9846999999, 29407.3069000002, 29406.9575999994, 29406.6139000002, 
29406.4900000002, 29404.7743999995, 29404.2050000001, 29403.9801000003, 
29403.0908000004, 29401.1268000007, 29401.1150000002, 29401.0921, 
29401.0811000001, 29401.0484999996, 29401.0371000003, 29401.0254999995, 
29401.0141000003, 29400.9931000005, 29400.9814999998, 29400.9612000007, 
29400.9521999992, 29400.9417000003, 29400.9233999997, 29400.9127999991, 
29400.9025999997, 29400.8924000002, 29400.8717999998, 29400.8618000001, 
29400.8419000003, 29400.8300000001, 29400.8098000009, 29400.7981000002, 
29400.7566, 29400.7446999997, 29400.7336999997, 29400.7224000003, 
29400.6988999993, 29400.6887999997, 29400.6677999999, 29400.6644000001, 
29400.6478000004, 29400.6447000001, 29400.6053999998, 29400.6022999994, 
29400.5746999998, 29400.5711000003, 29400.0042000003, 29399.5033, 
29398.8213999998, 29398.2977000009, 29397.5074000005, 29397.1119999997, 
29396.6135000009, 29396.4629999995, 29396.2002000008, 29395.4317000005, 
29394.5527999997, 29394.0800000001, 29394.0516999997, 29393.2323000003, 
29393.0877999999, 29393.0876000002, 29393.0844999999, 29393.1078999992, 
29393.2716000006, 29393.4747000001, 29393.7793000005, 29394.1854999997, 
29394.3759000003, 29394.4902999997, 29395.1503999997, 29395.7598000001, 
29396.4199000001, 29397.4861999992, 29398.5018000007, 29399.4158999994, 
29400, 29400.7210000008, 29401.6589000002, 29402.8538000006, 
29403.8535999991, 29404.9438000005, 29406.1910999995, 29407.2957000006, 
29408.6715999991, 29409.1183000002, 29409.9141000006, 29410.1587000005, 
29411.0876000002, 29411.1377000008, 29411.2945000008, 29412.5993000008, 
29413.0055999998, 29414.1212000009, 29414.1361999996, 29414.2127, 
29414.2206999995, 29414.7692000009, 29414.8424999993, 29414.8472000007, 
29414.9053000007, 29417.3455999997, 29417.3508000001, 29419.9740999993, 
29419.7564000003, 29389.7949000001, 29388.9831000008, 29388.5465999991, 
29388.0122999996, 29388.0034999996, 29366.9464999996, 29366.9105999991, 
29358.4038999993, 29357.6274999995, 29357.0120999999, 29368.3311999999, 
29385.9798000008, 29407.3345999997, 29424.7320000008, 29436.0628999993, 
29450.4178999998, 29478.9357999992, 29525.1693999991, 29525.2235000003, 
29565.9534000009, 29577.7887999993, 29584.0091999993, 29611.3517000005, 
29680.0907000005, 29680.0954, 29686.6875, 29691.7969000004, 29730.3905999996, 
29772.8358999994, 29772.8904999997, 29808.8155000005, 29831.4013, 
29831.6370000001, 29844.5855999999, 29857.4427000005, 29865.3944000006, 
29875.8423999995, 29901.6495999992, 29935.1447999999, 29941.1370000001, 
29965.2258000001, 29957.9716999996, 29951.2741999999, 29950.2839000002, 
29947.0336000007, 29945.4583000001, 29942.6499000005, 29940.5660999995, 
29940.3751999997, 29930.8670000006, 29944.5030000005, 29967.1778999995, 
29978.2590999994, 29982.4100000001, 29947.2529000007, 29943.6999999993, 
29936.7331000008, 29919.9718999993, 29976.3247999996, 29980.5318, 
30023.1938000005, 30038.2259999998, 30043.3059999999, 30007.7750000004, 
30043.4519999996, 30077.5490000006, 30091.3444999997, 30105.0640999991, 
30113.5877999999, 30113.9460000005, 30136.9189999998, 30139.4774999991, 
30146.6252999995, 30160.3751999997, 30169.2265000008, 30175.1327, 
30177.7272999994, 30170.8394000009, 30163.5427000001, 30160.648, 
30149.0843000002, 30142.5607999992, 30130.5416999999, 30095.6641000006, 
30094.5899, 30091.3056000005, 30057.5189999994, 30057.5086000003, 
30040.9020000007, 30026.6353999991, 30025.7526999991, 30021.8877000008
), dim = c(306L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"
)), structure(list(list(structure(c(29932.3320000004, 29947.3169, 
29870.4626000002, 29870.3020000001, 29870.057, 29856.9842999997, 
29855.4530999996, 29854.3136, 29821.1522000004, 29807.3196, 29805.1447999999, 
29765.6973000001, 29626.7991000004, 29608.8302999996, 29603.5955999997, 
29600.1534000002, 29543.0291999998, 29533.8768999996, 29511.9806000004, 
29462.2344000004, 29422.1211000001, 29368.5800999999, 29361.0927999998, 
29346.0345999999, 29335.4759, 29333.9323000005, 29351.2593999999, 
29361.3485000003, 29384.9842999997, 29420.8349000001, 29435.3663999997, 
29460.7576000001, 29517.2183999997, 29569.8885000004, 29640.0537, 
29764.8945000004, 29768.108, 29777.2970000003, 29787.2149999999, 
29788.4142000005, 29792.1858999999, 29807.7000000002, 29822.2139999997, 
29839.2319999998, 29851.2471000003, 29889.7929999996, 29901.8051000005, 
29932.3320000004, 29879.1198999994, 29858.0163000003, 29801.9734000005, 
29801.9036999997, 29801.7973999996, 29796.1232999992, 29795.4590000007, 
29795.0603999998, 29783.4626000002, 29778.6249000002, 29777.8643999994, 
29796.5239000004, 29862.2250999995, 29870.7245000005, 29862.2598000001, 
29856.5842000004, 29762.3945000004, 29766.6348999999, 29781.5136999991, 
29808.9406000003, 29831.0566000007, 29860.6445000004, 29865.1129000001, 
29874.0998, 29880.9927999992, 29882.0004999992, 29902.0461999997, 
29913.9366999995, 29941.8074999992, 29983.6171000004, 30000.5640999991, 
30029.9837999996, 30096.6920999996, 30161.1150000002, 30247.1771000009, 
30176.9066000003, 30174.6110999994, 30167.3568999991, 30159.5950000007, 
30158.0950000007, 30154.0811000001, 30130.0840000007, 30104.5889999997, 
30070.0930000003, 30042.0969999991, 29947.1088999994, 29922.1119999997, 
29879.1198999994), dim = c(48L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
"sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 28160.2259, 
ymin = 28369.4679000005, xmax = 32362.3935000002, ymax = 30247.1771000009
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:3414", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"SVY21 / Singapore TM\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"SVY21\",\n        DATUM[\"SVY21\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4757]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Singapore Transverse Mercator\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",1.36666666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",103.833333333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",1,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",28001.642,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",38744.572,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"northing (N)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"easting (E)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Cadastre, engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Singapore - onshore and offshore.\"],\n        BBOX[1.13,103.59,1.47,104.07]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3414]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(PLN_AREA_N = NA_integer_, 
REGION_N = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", "aggregate", 
"identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using st_join from the sf package.

```
library(sf)


JOINED_DATA <- st_join(ZIP, NEW_ZONE)
```

In this case though no data joined to you points as none of your points overlap the polygons, and the all seem to be within a meter of each other out in the ocean.  It looks as though the coordinates might be in lat long even though the crs is identified as SVY21.